# WTX CONVERT() function

Tags: wtx

How convert() function  works in WTX?

I have code like this. CONVERT(input element,"|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| |""#$%&'()*+,-.|0123456789:;|=|?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ|\||_|abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}||" )

Answer (score 1):

Convert has 2 arguments. First byes to be replaced. Second replaceable bytes. Syntax : convert(bytes_to_replace, replaceable_bytes).

It is usually used to convert data from ASCII to EBCDIC or from EBCDIC to ASCII .

Answer (score 0):

The ordinal for each byte in bytes_to_converts points the nth byte in the replacement bytes.

e.g. if there is a A in bytes_to_convert, it gets replaced by the 65th byte in the replacement bytes